# filter instances based on multiple tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Hi I'm unable to filter the instances based on multiple tags. It is able to do for one filter condition when I provide two tag in the filter it comes out as null. I think it is taking as "AND" in the filter. Is there any way to tell as OR in the filter condition. We have tag keys a both Environment and environment, it would be helpful to fetch both the details rather then using two filter conditions separately.

```
#define the connection region ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name="us-east-1") s3 = boto3.client('s3')

custom_filter = [
    {
        'Name':'tag:Enviroment', 
        'Values': ['*']
    },   
    {
        'Name':'tag:environment',
        'Values': ['*']
    } 
]
     def lambda_handler(event,context):
    response = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
    Reservation_details = response["Reservations"]
    for instance_details in Reservation_details:
        instances = instance_details.get("Instances")
        print(instances)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, each item in the filter list is treated to be an intersection and items in `VALUES` list of filter item a union.

To filter across tag key, where instances have tag key of `Environment` or `environment` not caring about the value of the tag key, you can write `custom_filter` to be:

```
custom_filter = [
    {
        'Name':'tag-key', 
        'Values': ['Environment', 'environment']
    }
]
```